# UITableView limit scrolling speed OR UITableView limit number of rows to be scrolled

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I just saw a brilliant application [**Nimbuzz**](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/nimbuzz-messenger/id297574648?mt=8). In its chat window, when there are couple of messages and we scroll the `UITableView`, what appears to be is, scrolling speed is slow. It may sound weird what I just said. You may also consider it this way. On scrolling the table, not much rows are scrolled in comparison to usual scroll behavior.

I am creating an application where I need the similar feature. How to do that?

Comment: turn off the scrolling in the table view but add gestures and implement your own responses (slow scrolling) to the swipe gestures?

Comment: Or you could overlay a `UIScrollView` on top of the `UITableView` and attach some `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to 'forward' the scroll position to the table (with a custom factor)

Answer (score 1):

I think you do that with scrollview's `decelerationRate` property. Since tableview is subview of scrollview it would work.